# EntityCommandExecutionException happening only on AzureSQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I do have the following Class and Controller

```
    public class FieldHelper
    {
        public FieldHelper(RoomMeta rm, string typeClass)
        {
            this.typeClass = typeClass;
            this.Name = rm.Name;
            if (rm.Required)
                this.required = "required";
            else
                this.required = "optional";
        }

        public FieldHelper(EventTypeMeta etm, string typeClass)
        {
            this.typeClass = typeClass;
            this.Name = etm.Name;
            if (etm.Required)
                this.required = "required";
            else
                this.required = "optional";
        }

        public string typeClass { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string required { get; set; }
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetDefaultFields(int eventTypeID, int roomID)
    {
        using (var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            List<FieldHelper> fields = new List<FieldHelper>();
            foreach(RoomMeta rm in db.RoomMetaSet.Where(rm => rm.RoomId == roomID))
            {
                fields.Add(new FieldHelper(rm, rm.FieldTypes.Name)); //Here the Exception gets thrown
            }
            foreach(EventTypeMeta etm in db.EventTypeMetaSet.Where(etm => etm.EventTypeId == eventTypeID))
            {
                fields.Add(new FieldHelper(etm, etm.FieldTypes.Name));
            }
            return Json(fields, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

My database layout looks as follows:

[image: database layout]

Now, when I run this on my local machine, where I use a SQL Server Express 2014 installation, everything works just the way I expected it. However, once I deploy the Application to a Windows Azure Website with a Azure SQL Database, I get an EntityCommandExecutionException at the line marked. The inner exception tells me "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." which seems somehow more useful to me, but still I couldn't figure out why this works localy but not online.

Any Ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've found the Answer myself. Since I didnt Include the related Entitys in my query, entity framework tried to open another connection, which failed due to the restriction of my azure sql database.

I changed

```
        foreach(RoomMeta rm in db.RoomMetaSet.Where(rm => rm.RoomId == roomID))
```

to

```
        foreach(RoomMeta rm in db.RoomMetaSet.Include("FieldTypes").Where(rm => rm.RoomId == roomID))
```

and everything works fine now.